# Cross-Domain AJAX workarounds without jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have custom AJAX code on a blog page that I set up to access my PHP files on my own domain, but oh no! I can't do that.

I would use jQuery to work around this, but can't, because I cannot upload the apparently neccessary jQuery.js to the website, as it is not mine.

Is there a way to access PHP requests by modifying HTML **only** on a page?

Comment: jQuery can do nothing JavaScript can't do alone, and is limited to what plain JavaScript is allowed to do - so no, it is obviously not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can link to external sites from your site you don't have to host jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Deleted my answer. Yea, should use this CDN version of jQuery. You don't need to host jQuery yourself!